# Test class for mimicing email to case functionality

Tags: email2case

I'm wondering if anyone can help. I have an after insert trigger on a case that needs to check for the case's from email address and based on certain conditions perform different actions.

We have email-to-case functionality in place that automatically creates cases for our support team if the email is sent to our support@ address. In my test class I am trying to insert a case and associate it to an email message. I can't see how to do this though. I need to be able to run through the scenario of creating a case from an email.

Can anyone help me out please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to create an instance of your class that implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler in the test method and then pass it a [Messaging.InboundEmail](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound.htm#apex_classes_email_inbound_inbound) and  [Messaging.InboundEnvelope](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_inbound_envelope.htm). This will create the Case and associate it with the email.

E.g.

```
global class EmailToCaseHandler implements Messaging.inboundEmailHandler{ ... }


@isTest
private class EmailToCaseTest {
    static testMethod void testCaseFromEmail() {

        Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();
        email.subject = 'test email-to-case';

        Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();
        env.fromAddress = 'user@acme.com';

        EmailToCaseHandler emailHandler = new EmailToCaseHandler();
        emailHandler.handleInboundEmail(email, env);


        // Make assertions about the case that should be created.
    }
}
```

---

Maybe I misinterpreted what you were asking for... Do you just want to test a Case that is associated with a [EmailMessage](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm)?

Here you would first insert the `Case` before inserting the `EmailMessage`. When inserting the EmailMessage, use the Case.Id field to populate the EmailMessage.ParentId field.

---

**How can you find the EmailMessage that is associated with the Case via the EmailMessage.ParentId when the Case is being inserted.**

My answer here is that you can't. The EmailMessage is inserted into the database **after** the Case is because it needs to reference the Case.Id in the ParentId field. See [Trigger on Case EmailMessage](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16795/trigger-on-case-emailmessage)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for replying. My problem is that in my test class I'm inserting the case, then inserting the email with EmailMessage.ParentId=Case.Id, but inside my after insert case trigger when I query back the email message like so:

List<EmailMessage> emails = [Select FromAddress, ParentId, Incoming from EmailMessage Where ParentId = :c.Id ];

the list is empty. I need to be able to get at the case's assoicated email to check the FromAddress of the email so that I can do certain actions based on the email domain.

Thanks again Daniel.

Brian.

Comment: I think I see the problem. You want to find the EmailMessage that is associated with the Case via the EmailMessage.ParentId when the Case is inserted. I've extended my answer.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you very much for your help - I really appreciate it. I had a feeling alright yesterday that I would have to go down the route of writing a trigger on the EmailMessage object because I couldn't get the association to the email message no matter what I tried in the case trigger. Thanks again for your help and the very useful link to the example of a trigger on EmailMessage.